# findNode in binary search tree

Tags: c++, find, binary-search-tree

Does this look right? I mean I am trying to implement the delete function.

```
Node* BST::findNode(int tofind) {
    Node* node = new Node;    
    node = root;
    while (node != NULL) {
        if (node->val == tofind) {
            return node;
        } else if (tofind < node->val) {
            node = node->left;
        } else {
            node = node->right;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the delete, it's not even close to done but,

```
void BST::Delete(int todelete) {

    // bool found = false;

    Node* toDelete = new Node();
    toDelete=findNode(todelete);
    if(toDelete->val!=NULL) {
            cout << toDelete->val << endl;
    }
}
```

This causes a segmentation fault just running that, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

oh wait it's because in delete I should have done:

```
if(toDelete!=NULL) {
  cout << toDelete->val << endl;
}
```

before it was

```
if(toDelete->val!=NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with `findNode()` is that you never return the node that you've found. That's why you're getting the segfault.

Also, in `deleteNode()` you should check whether `findNode()` has returned `NULL`. And of course you also need to code up the rest of the deletion logic.

Finally, the two `new Node` allocations are unnecessary and are leaking memory.